# Meteor: Can't display my text

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, meteor-helper

I would like to build a website using Meteor. Here just an example of my html code.

```
<head>
    <title>version_0.0.4</title>
</head>

<body>
     <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
     {{> myTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="myTemplate">
    <p id="&firstContent">Test to show my first content</p>
    <p id="&secondContent">Test to show my second content</p>
    <button type="button" id="save">Save content</button>
</template>
```

Now when someone is pressing the save content i would like to save the innerHtml of all id's with a "&" sign at the beginning in my database, that works fine.

```
    /* ----- functions to include ----- */
function inputContent(collection, inhalt, alteID){
    var id = collection.insert({
        content: inhalt,
        htmlId: alteID
    });
    return id;
}     

Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click #save': function () {
        $(document).ready(function() {    //Damit der Code erst ausgeführt wird, wenn der DOM geladen ist
            var all = $('*[id^="&"]');      // Das "&" Zeichen ist der Identifier/ in all speichern aller elemente
            console.log(all);
                for (var i = 0; i < all.length; ++i) {
                    var item = all[i];  //Durch all iterieren
                    var idNeuesItem = inputContent(textList, item.innerHTML, item.id);//Enthält ID über Callback
                    console.log("Gespeichert :" + textList.findOne({_id: idNeuesItem}).content);
                } 
            });
        }
  });
```

After i did this ones,i delete the innerHtml code manually at the moment so that my htmt file looks like that:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
<p id="&firstContent"></p>
<p id="&secondContent"></p>
<button type="button" id="save">Save content</button>
```

Now i want a possability to display the content inside my id's so that for the user it looks like before, but the content is coming from the database. i already tried diffrent versions but none of them worked. Could someone please help me ? And sorry when this is a nooby question, i'm pretty new to meteor ...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a helper method to publish certain attributes of the JSON object you are storing to your database.

Yours would look something like this (written server-side)

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  item: function () {
    return itemList.findOne({_id: idNeuesItem});  //retrieve item
  }
});
```

And then you would have to place it in the template sort of like this:

```
 <p id="&firstContent">
  {#with item}
        {{content}}
  {/with]
  </p>
```

Read more about using Meteor and Spacebars here:
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/